# How to close an existing form after opening another form?

Tags: c#, forms

new to c# wandered how i can use a form to open a new form whilst also closing that initial form. I have a form that a user needs to fill out and click login on to move forward which at this point if the information is correct should open the next form and close the current one. All i seem to get is both forms closing. i can do it without closing the initial form but then it is obviously still open in the background. The form i'm trying to open is form encryption and the one 'im trying to close is form1 any help is much appreciated.

here's my code:

```
if (maskedTxtLogin != null)
        {
            FormEncryption Encryption = new FormEncryption();

            Encryption.Show();

            this.Close();

        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please input your initials");
        }
```

Comment: it depend on whether your "initial" form is the application form (or the Main form). You cannot close the Main form (which is the Application form) and expect the child still running. The **this** could be referring to your Main form.

Comment: The initial form is the login form. The main form is the one that is opened by the initial form. Is their any way around this child form issue? maybe have it open from the beginning but invisible and then becomes visible when the other one is closed? do you think this could work? cheers for any help

Comment: According to Windows, the main form is the initial form. Whichever is the first form to open must stay alive for the whole life of the application. So yes, what you describe would work better.

Comment: Okay thanks anyway guys !

Comment: You can control when your application closes by using a custom [ApplicationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.applicationcontext?view=netframework-4.7.2).  The `Application.Run(new Form1())` statement in `Program.Main` create a default `ApplicationContext` with `Form` as its main form.  By using a custom ApplicationContext and overriding the `OnMainFormClosed` method, you can redefine `MainForm` as it is just a property of the context.  You start the application using `Application.Run(new CustomApplicationContext)`.

Comment: I found a way around it but thanks anyway. Ended up just running the form from the start of the initial form but with 0 opacity and then altering both the initial form and the form i wanted to opens opacity at the click of the button to 'close' or just hide the initial form and 'open' or just make visible the new form. Thanks anyway guys!